# how to port existing wpf desktop apps to Windows 10 universal apps

Tags: wpf, win-universal-app, windows-10

So I have an existing windows desktop application which is written using WPF. I searched through the net for possible ways of upgrading it to Windows 10 universal app but cant seem to find anything on this upgrade path. There are documentation available to port WPF desktop app to WinRT (which according to my understanding is no same as Universal platform) but nothing on this topic.

This link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn751495.aspx
shows up options to "Port your app to the Universal Windows Platform (UWP)" but doesn't mention anything for this upgrade path.

So I am curious if this is even possible? If yes, are there any documentation or examples to follow? If no, why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot upgrade a WPF app to a Windows 10 Universal app, because those are very different platforms.
Both have capabilities and markups that doesn't exist or have an equivalent in the other.
So there is no "simple" upgrade path, you would have to rewrite a lot of UI but you can maybe reuse the "business" part if it's written in a Portable Class Library.